# OmniVision CMOS sensor package name for camera modules?

Tags: connector, cmos, camera, packages, ribbon-cable

I seen few camera modules by [OV](http://www.ovt.com/products/), that come on a flex cable like the one below (OV2640)
[image]

How does this package called? I see on the OV website COB, CSP, uCSP,CLGA, but I suspect they're without the enclosed lens and cable. Does OV makes those, or some third party buys the sensor and mounts the lens/cable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All mobile style cameras I came across used one of any of the three common Mobile Industry Processor Interface (MIPI) connectors.

1. The one shown above is an FFC/FPC connector style.
2. LVDS FFC.
3. Board to Board connector.

Both LVDS FFC and FFC/FPC look almost the same, while the BtB connector is different. The connector above is a 30-pin FFC/FPC 0.5mm pitch connector style. I have seen CMOS cameras coming in 24 and 30 pin FFC/FPC connector styles. [Hirose](https://www.hirose-connectors.com) and [Molex](http://www.molex.com/) are two out of many companies that manufactur the mating connectors and similar cables.

The CMOS chip is manufactured by [OmniVision](http://www.ovt.com/) but thirt party companies like [Sunny Optical](http://www.sunnyoptical.com/en/default.html) package it together with the lense and connector. Most of those third party manufacturers only do Business-to-Business sales and rarely do sale those modules indevidually.

[image][image][image]